# Crystal for ATMEGA32u4 Not Working

Tags: atmega, crystal

I have been trying to make a watch circuit, but have ran into the issue of how to setup the crystal. I believe it is the crystal that is the problem because when I messed with the crystal contacts the microcontroller starting completing the blink program I had put in it. It made me believe that the crystal was not oscillating and I don't know why. I am totally confused on how to fix it because all the circuits look like they just have the resonator and the capacitors. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Wiring for the Crystal

[image]

Comment: 1) **Why** would you want to replace(?) the crystal? 2) What crystal is used needs to be programmed into the MCU, did you know this? 3) If you get that setting wrong the timing of this MCU will be incorrect so it might not be able to communicate over the serial bus anymore. 4) The most common solution to make a watch circuit with an MCU is to use a real-time module like a DS3231 module.

Comment: I am using a RTC for time keeping, but what setting do I need to change in the code to fix the crystal?

Comment: Define fix and “mess with”

Comment: I don't really understood what happened I just was trying to measure the voltage of the XTAL1 and XTAL2 and then the lights I was trying to control turned on. I was running a blink script, so it leads me to believe that the crystal wasn't oscillating, so when I affected the crystal pins on the ATMEGA it progressed a cycle.

Comment: *trying to measure the voltage of the XTAL1 and XTAL2* And you're doing that using an **oscilloscope with a 10:1 probe** I hope? You don't need to change your code, you need to change the "fuses" setting **if** you're using a crystal that has a **different frequency** than the one that the ATMega is currently programmed for. You still haven't explained **WHY** you are changing the crystal. Why don't you use a ready-made Arduino board (which will include a working crystal) and experiment with that?

Comment: Well I want this board to be really compact so I don't want to scale it up when I can just add my own crystal. Also when I did this on a board with 16mhz it worked fine, so I thought it would be easy.

Comment: Crystal oscillators are basically little radio circuits, lost in a sea of digital-ness.  As such, the layout of your circuit is very important.  Please edit your question with a screenshot of your board layout (or a photo of your board, if you're putting this together by hand) that includes the oscillator pins, the crystal, and the caps.  If you made a moat of ground traces around the oscillator -- good, but include those in your screenshot.

Comment: Based on the fact that the oscillator seemed to start working when you probed it -- that may be exactly what happened.  If you have something that basically works, but can't start up, there's hope.

Comment: I changed the question to include the basic PCB

Comment: Have you programmed any fuse? Please add whether and which. If the oscillator has been properly configured (fuses, see the complete datasheet section 6.2) consider lowering the capacitors down to at least 12pF. Note that probing the crystal will influence the behavior of the oscillator.